# implementing of pop() method in a stack

Tags: java

I have a `pop()` method in Java I want to implement it. Here is my code:

```
public E pop() {
    if (top == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else {
        return top.element;
        top = top.next;
    }
}
```

But my book do it like this:

```
public E pop() {
    if (top == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    E tmp = top.element;
    top = top.next;
    return tmp;
}
```

Is my way of doing peek() method correct?

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Comment: Well, the version of your book is valid Java code, whereas yours isn't what does this tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` means two things:

- use the value following the `return` statement as the result of the function call
- stop execution of the function and return the control flow to the caller.

Your understanding of `return` seems to suggest that you missed the second point.

Java is kind of smart and will fail the compilation of your program because it detects that `top = top.next;` is an unreachable statement. Not all languages/compilers do this.

Your implementation of peek is equivalent to that in the book.

As a side note:

- It is beneficial to learn to write unit tests to verify correctness of your program.
- It is beneficial to learn programming on your computer instead of on a paper.

Answer (score 3):

Your `top=top.next;` won't be executed because of the the return-statement in the line before. You have to save the Object you pop temporarly to set the new top.